# Sending a broadcast to an activity that is not in the activity stack

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an application with many activities.

the application's state is saved by data i receive from the internet- via web service

at one time or another, my webservice will tell me that i need to perform login, after i have already logged in, in the past, and the login activity is not on the activity stack.

I want, when i receive the info to relogin (in http related classes), to send a broadcast to the system, to open the login activity.

where do i need to register this broadcast receiver, as i may be in any activity, when this broadcast arrives ?

Comment: broadcast receiver if it doesn't depend on any component in app make it in manifest , it will listen for actions if the app not active

Comment: **"my webservice will tell me that i need to perform login"** - How does it tell you this? Also, surely all you need to do is use `startActivity(...)` to start the login activity???

Comment: the class that receives the message of needing to relogin, is not an activity class, it is a business logic class, i do not want to start an activity from there, because this class may move to another application, as i often do, i can however, send a broadcast from there, because i do not care if there is a receiver for it, i notify the app globally of the event

Comment: for the question : how does it tell you this: i receive an httpresponse, to any request i send, that tells me my login is no longer valid

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know *a priori* which `Activity` will be running when the signal is sent, the best way is defining it in the `Manifest` file, like this:

```
<receiver android:name="YourReceiver" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register you BroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml like this

```
<receiver android:name=".YourBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.INETENT_NAME" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

If your broadcast is for handling internal intents only, make sure you declare it as `exported false` else some other applications can interrupt and open your login anytime just by sending a broadcast.

**EDIT :**

Here name is the exact path of your BroacastReceiver with package name. If it resides in your main package dot(.) is enough because the reference is taken from package defined inside manifest tag but if it reside in some other package like yourcommonapppackage.broadcastreceiver.YourBroadcastReceiver you have to give the name accordingly.

You can give whether full full with package or with reference to your main package.

Comment: I tried that, however the broadcast doesnt seem to be received

Comment: maybe i'm missing something ? i put this code in the manifest, declared a class with the same name, and wrote the logic into it, then i put Intent intent = new Intent("THE_NAME_OF_THE_ACTION"); context.sendBroadcast(intent);

Comment: @LenaBru is your BroadcastReceiver inside your root application package, which is defined in mainifest on very first line. if not add the subpackage in name attribute like `.yourreceiver.YourBroadcastReceiver`

Comment: in my manifest, the package of the broadcast receiver is like this com.namespace.appname.broadcastreceivers.broadcastreceivername

and my broadcast receiver resides at this location

Comment: Then better to include your manifest and code of sending broadcast in question itself So I can answer .